# How to access Amazon DynamoDB via JavaScript AWS SDK Version 3 with just browser based JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use version 3 of the AWS SDK (JavaScript) to work with AWS.  I built the sdk to contain @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb and renamed it to aws-sdk-js-v3.js and added it to my index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/aws-sdk-js-v3.js"></script>
```

In version 2 of the SDK, you just used AWS to reference the library.  I can't figure out how to access the SDK in version 3.  All the examples I have found are node.js examples.  I am hoping for an example that shows how to use version 3 of the AWS SDK in browser-based JavaScript. Maybe ListTablesCommand for DynamoDB example?

Comment: I need the same thing but I did not find a method. Perhaps we do need to include node.js. I am also looking into browserify.

Answer (score 1):

To learn how to work with Amazon DynamoDB and the AWS SDK for JavaScript V3, please refer to the DEV guide. Here is a good place to start:

[Amazon DynamoDB examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-examples.html)

In addition, you can find many other code examples for the  AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 in Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascriptv3/example_code

I know that some developers refer to service guides and not these resources to learn how to work with AWS Services and  AWS SDK for JavaScript V3, but these resources are the best ones to refer to in order to learn how to use this SDK.